# how to split an object-fraction from objectlist?

Tags: java

I had an assignment earlier and part of the problem included reading a set of fractions as a string array and then splitting each fraction in the numerator and denominator form while converting it into an integer. So I used

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        split = fractions[i].split("/"); 
        //splits the fraction at that point

        //Converts the split string fraction to integer
        numerator[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
        denominator[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
}
```

and the code went so on....
so the code worked fine and everything was good.
Now instead of using an array of string variable I have been asked to make a separate class called Objectlist that contains a list of `Objects` and use that to split the fraction.
So far I did

```
//Variable for storing numerators
private int numerator;

//variable for storing denominators
private int denominator;

ObjectList fractions = new ObjectList();

//Variable for an array used to split the fraction
private Object[] split = new String[2];

split = (fractions.split("/"); //splits the fraction at that point

    //Converts the split string fraction to integer
    numerator = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
    denominator = Integer.parse Int(split[1]);
```

and so on....
so when i declare the split variable as an object i get 3 errors, split not defined in object list and conversion with parse Int. 
When i declare the split variable as a string i get 1 error, the split not being defined in the object list one.

i am really confused on as to how to approach this one because i am pretty sure i am missing something. Any help would be great.

Comment: I don't believe the code snippet you provided will even compile.  Can you tidy things up a bit?

Comment: no its part of a bigger class.....the first part i posted the class complies and gives me the right result as well. The second part of the code is also part of a larger class and the only error i am getting is for the split function.....when i comment it out all other functions work fine.

Comment: The syntax `split = (fractions.split("/");` looks completely broken to me.  Did this ever compile?

Comment: @Tim yes it did....as i mentioned above.....@Titus I tried that already and because my fraction is of type Object its giving me an error.